# How to re-download incomplete podcast downloads in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, podcast

It seems like Rhythmbox has a bad habit of not downloading some of the podcast files completely:

[image: Incompletely downloaded podcasts]

But I don't seem to find the option of re-downloading the episode anywhere. Deleting the episode, either from within Rhythmbox or from the file system doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Right-click on the file, click **Properties**. Click on the **Details** tab. 
Copy the **Source** property to clipboard. (you may have to stretch the window to see the whole URL). Go to the download location in terminal.

Make a mental note of the file name Rhythmbox saved as (not the same as download file name, but similar.)

```
wget -c -O [Download location file name] [Source location, as copied/pasted].
```

`wget` will auto-retry until complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml and remove the  line corresponding to the file you want to re-download.
Do it when rhythmbox is not running, of course (it will rewrite its config on close).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. However, I had this issue when moving my `rhythmdb.xml` file from a backup to a clean Ubuntu install (17.10).

I resolved it by opening
`~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`  and searching for `<status>100</status>` and `<status>103</status>`

Next, I replaced  those lines with `<status></status>`

once I did that next time I started up Rhythmbox started re-downloading my podcast files.